# What is your dream job?

Tags: sound-design, job, projects

Now that you're in the entertainment industry, what would be your most ideal job to work on?

I grew up watching Shark Week on the Discovery Channel so I wouldn't mind sound designing and mixing that series.

Walking with Dinosaurs would be extremely fun.

I would love to do a war film like Saving Private Ryan. I love the detail and intimacy of the foley in that film - they went to town on it.

Anything Pixar. If it has the name Pixar on it, I don't care what it is I'll do it!

Ultimately I want to design something which goes down in the history books which has augmented an industry-changing film and which kids will mimic for years to come and has left a stamp on the sound designing field (i.e. lightsabers, vader's breath, etc.)

What sort of shows or movies did you watch as a kid that you would love to design?

Any dreams you have for the future? Where do you ultimately want to take your career?

Answer (score 7):

I get the feeling that you're looking for 'job' as in 'project' not 'job' as in 'career.' It's probably because I haven't reached my ultimate career goal, but for me one project is not inherently better than another. Certainly, some projects provide more obvious opportunities for our work than others. But for me it's the atmosphere and energy surrounding the project, created by the team who's working on it, that makes a job a dream to be a part of.

Having said that, my dream, my goal, is to work on film. I want to be a part of a team of sound effects editors who work with a supervising sound editor who is brought on early in the production process, whose opinions on how to use sound to tell a better story are discussed and validated before the picture is shot (I'll take before it's edited, but we are talking *dreams* here).  I want to take part in sound effect recording sessions in junkyards, on tarmacs, out in the desert, or across the reaches of the globe if necessary. I want to spend a week designing a scene just to have it play second fiddle to the score. I yearn for spotting sessions where a vision is shared, and frantic last-minute editing when the vision has changed (or wasn't met). Situations that push the limits of my abilities, and so that I can grow into a best editor and mixer I can be. But most importantly co-workers who are comrades and coaches, who after long hard days of collaboration you still want to have a beer with.

Comment: I've been trying to extol the virtues of beer alongside sound design on Twitter but haven't had much success yet.

Comment: @ianjpalmer I'm more of a scotchy whisky guy myself. Smaller glass means less liquid around the desk! lol ;)

Comment: Same here, Steve Urban, same here.

Comment: Nice answer! That's pretty much what I want, too. I don't like beer, though!

Answer (score 6):

I want to work with a team of sound professionals that create a vision and are all committed to a high end product. I want to design and mix and see a directors eyes sparkle on the dub stage with the glorious full manifestation of what was once only a dream and now sings more vibrantly in reality.

I want to be challenged.  I want to worry if I am good enough, struggle to find inspiration, be proven wrong, have to prove myself, and be forced to do better.

I want to create something that brings goose bumps, laughter, and tears to the audience. I want to tell an amazing story with sound that will seep into the thoughts and minds of the masses. That is the aim of my dreams and career.

Answer (score 4):

I've been lucky that I think I've already done my dream job, twice!  I'm a huge James Bond fan and I worked on the Quantum of Solace game.  The highlight for me was going to Pinewood Studios in England (where all the Bond movies have been filmed) and recording Judi Dench.  I also got to travel Europe recording a couple Bond villains and Bond girls.  Last month, I got to revisit the Bond world and design gun sounds for an upcoming Bond game.

Aside from that, I'd love to work on an Indiana Jones film.

Comment: @Chuck - I don't know if I already posted this story but when I watched the most recent Indiana Jones I was listening to the sound effects of the punches and they sounded almost identical to the earlier movie's punches and I turned to my friend and I said "I bet you they used the original sound effects for those punches from the old movies" and sure enough, Ben Burtt did restore the original punches and other elements for the new one. Hah!

Comment: @Ryan - That's the thing, when you work on a continuation of a franchise that has iconic elements, you shouldn't be changing things.  It would be like doing a new R2D2 or new lightsaber sound for the Prequel movies.

Comment: Traveling through Europe recording Bond girls... yeah that sounds pretty dreamy @Chuck.

Answer (score 4):

Without doubt 2 dream things I'd jump at doing would be anything from the Star Trek universe or Doctor Who.

Whatever your thoughts on Trek the sound has been some great work in every series!

My sound-geek favourite would have to be Doctor Who though. The work by the BBC's Radiophonic Workshop was simply genius! And the guys in Bang Post Production have done a terrific job on combining a completely modern sound design but with some of the old material in there for good measure.

Comment: Agreed across the board, there. Some great and iconic sounds in both those shows.

Answer (score 4):

My ultimate dream job is working at Skywalker.  Working with the amount of creative genius that resides in that building, working on the biggest projects around, having resources that nobody else has... amazing.

On another note, I think it would be absolutely amazing to work production sound for Mythbusters.  I've always thoroughly enjoyed blowing stuff up, and many of the other things they do on that show.  I can only imagine how much fun it would be to work on that set...

When it comes down to it, my dream job would include working with people that understand my art, working for people that understand that I know what I'm doing and allow me to do what I think it best, making enough money to support me and my family without worrying, and having enough time left after work to breathe.  There are very few of these jobs in sound, but they are out there.

Comment: how about prod sound for Dirty Jobs??

Comment: @Jay - Ha!  That might get weird...  I think I'd be worried about the wellbeing of my equipment the whole time.  Although, I'm sure Mythbusters has blown up their fair share of equipment...

Comment: @Jay and @Colin There was a great article about the reality show The Deadliest Catch. They send audio equipment out and don't expect it to come back for the next season. Hah!

Comment: @Ryan - they use the Sound Devices 302 on that show. I bet no other mixer could hold up as well!

Comment: @Colin - I've been out there twice to work.  It is indeed a phenomenal experience.  I was a little intimidated at first, but the crew there is top notch.  Quality folks.

Answer (score 4):

+1 on Mixing Maniac's post.

I often am asked to be all-in-one operator - sound editor, sound designer, ADR recordist/editor, foley artist/editor, mix engineer, music supervisor.  The upside is that I've taught myself these arts through trial and error and have honed my skills.  I hope, at least.

I would like nothing more than to be surrounded by a team of sound professionals who are collaborating indefinitely and pushing one another.  To work on a film project where the sound crew is invited to the table at the same time the rest of the crew is invited.  To work as a team instead of going it alone.

I have, however, had the chance to work on a dream project that has just made the Oscar nomination short list for live-action short film - "Ana's Playground".  Eric Howell is an talented director who understands the role and the importance that sound plays in film.  He gave me creative license to explore the space that the film takes place in.  A rarity in my daily work!

Collaboration, I'm finding, is becoming a more and more vital element of the dream "job(s)" that I'm in search of.

Comment: Congrats on the Oscar nod!

Comment: Congrats indeed!

Answer (score 4):

To do foley and field recording for the rest of my life, everyday, developing great sonic landscapes with the best like Burtt, Meyers, Rydstrom, Thom, etc.

Comment: Nice!          .

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to work for David Lynch

Answer (score 2):

I'd kill to work on a Dungeons and Dragons video game, or anything by Blizzard or Bethesda.

Film wise, a Bond would be nice, but I think a Freddy / Jason slasher flick would be something I'd cherish forever.

Answer (score 2):

I think my dream job would be to travel the world capturing soundscapes much like the [Sound Tracker Gordon Hempton](http://www.soundtrackerthemovie.com/ST/Home.html). This would combine my two passions of sound and travel/nature. I'd also love to get involved in documenting underwater recordings for scientific research and nature documentaries (I'm a keen scuba diver and am fascinated by the underwater world).

That said, if Pixar or Skywalker Sound rang me up asking if I was available I wouldn't say no!

Answer (score 2):

To be a moderator for Social Sound Design, of course!

Answer (score 2):

I just recently got my dream job!  I am the in house sound designer at Hi-Rez Studios.  I am doing all the sound design for their new Tribes game!

www.BenjieFreund.com
www.NeutrinoGaming.com

Comment: Congrats! Great job.

Answer (score 2):

Skywalker, without a doubt. That's got to be the coolest gig ever.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to work on something that goes 50 seasons back to back.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice to be in Ren Klyce's shoes. To be in a position where you can be sound designer and re-recording mixer on films like Fight Club and Zodiac would be a dream job.

Answer (score 2):

Anything at Skywalker.

Answer (score 1):

I would love to work on some animation films or any major motion picture feature.  Working on video games would be really cool too.

Comment: It's easy to work on video games, if you're not shooting for big-budget games.  Forums like Kongregate usually can find you unpaid jobs.  For paid work, sometimes, TIGSource is good (http://forums.tigsource.com/), and the GameAudio Forum (www.gameaudioforum.com) has job opportunities, as well.

Just like any field, while you're building your demo, you're kind of limited to the jobs you can get, but once your reel is together you can be more selective.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Pixar! I love animation films! :P I'd love to work in those kind of projects as a sound editor.. or maybe  mixing it! I wouldn't mind to work with Dreamworks as well.. lol :) I think that most of the films are done by Skywalker sound, so ultimately I would love to work there!

Comment: Yeah, I think all of Pixar gets exclusively done at Skywalker. They're at the top of their game up there.

Comment: FYI: Pixar also has a small in house sound department.

Answer (score 1):

something crazy sci-fi with weird and deep atmospheres would be definately mine... Like District 9 or Aliens-Predator.  Or Walli-E - when i saw documentary about sound design for this piece I was fascinated! So that kind of work I dont mind at all!

Answer (score 1):

Skywalker... definitely, where it all started! Someone can say!

Answer (score 1):

For me it would be getting to work with certain directors & auteurs.....

- Kim Ki-Duk
- David Lynch
- Kiyoshi Kurosawa
- Jean Pierre Jeunet
- Mathew Barney
- Joon-ho Bong
- Apichatpong Weerasethakul
- Wes Anderson
- Wim Wenders
- Lars von Trier
- Terence Malick
- Park Chan-Wook
- Wong Ka Wai
- PT Anderson
- The Cohen Brothers

and lots more...

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to work with Terrance Malick or Craig Berkey one day. Really explore sound art within film.